# Azure Powershell Alerting

Tags: vb.net, powershell, azure

Currently I have a system that does backups to an azure storage blob. Within that blob I have a folder for each customers backups. I would like to be able to use powershell/vb to have each folder checked daily to see if there is a new file within the last 48 hours and if not to send am email alerting which folder does not have a backup. I have done very little programming in my life and what I have done was many moons ago. Could someone help me get started? Right now I am able to do a get-azurestorageblob which shows all the files with their directories and the dates but I have no idea how to use that information to do what I want to do. Thank you

Here is a small sample of the azure command when outputted to txt.

Name                  BlobType   Length                ContentType           LastModified          SnapshotTime
----                  --------   ------                -----------           ------------          ------------
80500/backup113013... BlockBlob  3135490287                                  12/1/2013 3:26:39 ...
80500/backup120113... BlockBlob  3133936105                                  12/2/2013 3:27:03 ...
80500/backup120213... BlockBlob  3137539329                                  12/3/2013 3:27:18 ...
90407/backup110113... BlockBlob  2484494132                                  11/2/2013 4:21:14 ...
90407/backup110213... BlockBlob  2484510293                                  11/3/2013 4:22:00 ...
90407/backup110313... BlockBlob  2484429713                                  11/4/2013 5:22:10 ...
90407/backup110413... BlockBlob  2484406856                                  11/5/2013 5:22:46 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone who hasn't done a lot of programming you've certainly made it pretty far just figuring out what tools you can use and getting PowerShell with Azure going this far.  I think the command you are looking for is this:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container yourContainerName | Where-Object { $_.LastModified -lt ((Get-Date).AddHours(-48)) }
```

One thing to know about PowerShell is almost all output of commands are actually objects.  The console just displays them to you in text.  What the command above is doing is taking in everything that comes out of the Get-AzureStorageBlob CmdLet you ran and running a check using the Where-Object cmdlet and anything that meets the criteria is then included in the output.  In this case I'm using the Get-Date Cmdlet to get the current time, subtracting 48 hours and checking the Last Modified date property.  This will output all of the files that have a Last Modified property of greater than 48 hours, which is what I think you are looking for.

Remember that the output of that command is a collection of objects, so you could then create an alert that included their names, etc.

I'd highly suggest picking up PowerShell in Action or watching the Intro to PowerShell course on Pluralsight.  They will help a LOT.

Comment: Awesome, this looks like exactly what I need. My next step will be having it send an email if a file does not exist in a folder that is within 48 hours. Would this be something I could do in powershell, within one script? I will definitely take a look at that course and start some training.

Comment: There's a cmdlet for that: send-mailmessage. :)

Comment: Thanks I will try to figure that out.

Comment: I am running that script but I still get items that were modified more than 48 hours ago. Also all the items get cut short ex.90533/backup110113... BlockBlob  3031309999                                  11/2/2013 3:44:08 ...        There are a bunch of ...'s why can I not see the whole thing? This is one that showed up when I ran that command. Does it only allow so many characters? Whether I output to .csv or .txt it doesn't seem to matter.

Comment: Look at format-list Cmdlet and other cmdlets for formatting the data.  It's all there as objects, you just may have to manually write it out.  As far as the more than 48 hours ago still showing up I thought that is what you wanted. You want the ones that hadn't been updated in more than 48 hours, correct?  If not, flip the -lt to -gt and that makes the logic grab a list of the ones that HAVE been modified in the last 48 hours.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I wanted. Now I need to create a way to read this file and check if any customer # is missing their backup and send an alert. Now it loos much nicer.

Comment: Ok I am getting closer to my goal. I am using Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "cloudbackup" | Where-Object { $_.LastModified -lt ((Get-Date).AddHours(-48)) } and select-string -path C:\azureps\output.txt -Pattern 50000/backup I intend to make one for each folder. How would I get it to send an email wit the folder number "50000" if the select-string returns any data? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure select-string is what you want. If you are using that to look through the output then you are missing the point of the fact that all the results are objects and are passed down the pipeline.  Think about the where-object and look at foreach-object as well to iterate your original results.